# PHP replace <br> with carriage return?

Tags: php, return

I have a basic PHP page listing records from a database, one on each line.

Currently I'm using `<br>` to move to the next line, but I really need to replace it with a carriage return instead, so it can be externally read like a text file.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Erm. Yes. You put a carriage return instead of the `<br>`. What part of this are you having a problem with, exactly? Is this file going to be downloaded so it can be externally read? (You may want to change the Content-Type of the page, in that case, so it's not HTML at all.)

Comment: It's not a PHP problem, but HTML. Use `<pre>` tag.

Comment: It's being read externally from another site and for their ease of use I didn't want BR tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If you want to use it as a text file you can use the header `text/plain` in combination with the carriage return.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type:text/plain");
    echo 'Rule 1'. "\r"; //*Note the dubble quote!*
    echo 'Rule 2'. "\r"; //*Note the dubble quote!*
?>
```

**Edit:**
After the (useful) comment of Matt Gibsen

You can also use a combination with "\n", like:

```
echo 'Rule 1'. "\r\n"; //*Note the dubble quote!*
```

When to use `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n` is dependent on the OS:

- **Linux/Unix**: \n
- **Windows**: \r\n

Comment: It depends on where this file is going, but you should bear in mind that most systems will want a `\n` or a `\r\n`, rather than a single `\r`, i.e. Line Feed (most suited to Unix systems) or Carriage Return/Line Feed combination (most suited to Windows systems.) (Some systems, e.g. Mac OS 9 and earlier, might have wanted a single carriage return, but it's pretty rare these days.)

Comment: NB: These days (OS X and above, which are all BSD Unix derivatives) Macs use a line feed, just like other unix flavours. A single \r hasn't been needed for Macs for a decade or more.

Comment: Didn't knew that, edited the answer. Thanks for the information.